# What libraries (or individual jars) do I need for a Java EE6 application?

Tags: java-ee-6

1. I want to know jars libraries are needed to run a basic EE6 application?
2. What is the EAR library? where can I find a listing of constituent these jars?
3. What is the Web App library? Where can I find a listing of these constituent jars?

Comment: Just to prevent any more down votes, I might suggest updating the question.  In terms of **running** a JavaEE6 application, you need JavaEE6 server.  In terms of **compiling** a JavaEE6 application, the jar you specify is just fine -- though you must remember to *not* include that jar in the application itself.  Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to get started with Java EE 6 is by using a Java EE 6 application server. These already contain all the jars that make up Java EE 6.

Examples are TomEE and Resin (both only 25mb), GlassFish, JBoss AS and Geronimo.

Nearly every part of Java EE is available as seperate jars as well, but you'll need to do a lot of jar hunting and need to make a lot of choices (for JSF, MyFaces or Mojarra, for JPA, Hibernate, EclipseLink, ..., for CDI OpenWebBeans, Weld or CanDI, etc).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to choose an application server for your project. [Creating an Enterprise Application Using Maven](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-entapp.html) gives you a good impression on how to build and deploy a Java EE6 application.

An [EAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_%28file_format%29) is an EnterpriseARchive as described in Wikipedia.

> EAR (Enterprise Archive) is a file format used by Java EE for
>   packaging one or more modules into a single archive so that the
>   deployment of the various modules onto an application server happens
>   simultaneously and coherently. It also contains XML files called
>   deployment descriptors which describe how to deploy the modules.